# WPF - Is the offset, when working on a slider, defined anywhere?

Tags: c#, wpf, background, slider, drawingbrush

I've been working on a proper slider for my C# WPF project.

I wanted to create a slider, with a background that indicates different parts of the process, by adding a different color to each section on the slider. Furthermore I wanted to add small indicators (like the default ticks, but custom shape and irregular position) to the background.

I achived this by creating a drawing brush and adding correspondingly colored rectangles. This seemed to work fine, but a small distortion was still present, so I investigated further and realized the following:

With slider.ActualWidth I get the width of the whole widget. So in order to create a background covering the actual "slider" part, I'll have to be aware of the distance from the widget to the actual slider. (See image)

[image]

I measured the distance in a very small window, in fullscreen and stretched on two screens. It seems this distance is always 5 pixels. I tried google and looked through the info WPF provides on its pages, but either I read over it, or there is no information on this.

Can I be sure this distance is always 5 pixels ? In there any place such information is kept ? Is there maybe another way, to determine the size of the slider itself?

Comment: *Image will follow at 10 reputation*... just supply the image URL and someone will add it for you.

Comment: The "5 pixels" distance you are talking about is defined in the default ControlTemplate for the Slider control. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish but it seems like you want to change the appearance of the Slider: for this you will need to change its ControlTemplate and possibly its Style. This page on MSDN might help: [Slider Styles and Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753256(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Sheridan The URL *was* in the markup, but as a footnote link. I'm not that familiar with image markup in Markdown, maybe the syntax was incorrect.

Comment: Another useful page you might like: [How to: Customize the Ticks on a Slider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746616(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, as @StevenRands noted, there is no point in duplicating code to create your own `Slider`.. .just define a new `ControlTemplate` instead. See the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you haven't tinkered with the Slider template you can just walk down the visual tree and check the ActualWidth of the track:

```
Border b = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(slider, 0) as Border;
Grid g = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(b, 0) as Grid;
Border track = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(g, 2) as Border;
Console.WriteLine("Track ActualWidth: " + track.ActualWidth);
```

Comment: No, I did not tinker with the template, so this worked flawless.